# 'CompletionHandler' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context

Tags: ios, swift, swift4, xcode10, swift4.2

I recently joined a new project and started working on iOS app codebase. However, with latest Xcode 10, the code no longer compiles.

```
protocol NetworkClientType {
  associatedtype CompletionHandler
  static func intoRequest(_ url: URL?) -> URLRequest?
}

extension NetworkClientType {

  typealias CompletionHandler = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void

  static func intoIncompleteURLSessionDataTask(_ request: URLRequest) -> (CompletionHandler) -> URLSessionDataTask {
    return { completion in URLSession(configuration: .default).dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: completion) }
  }
}
```

Then on line 10 (`static func intoIncompleteURLSessionDataTask...`), the compiler error says **'CompletionHandler' is ambiguous for type lookup in this context**

Does anyone know how to resolve this? I have googled around and couldn't find working solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
extension NetworkClientType {
  typealias CompletionHandler = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void
```

to

```
extension NetworkClientType 
    where CompletionHandler == (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void {
```

Comment: Hi matt, thanks for the reply. What if I have more than one associatedtype in the protocol, how would I write the `where` in the extension?

Comment: The same way (the where clause is a comma list). — The point is that an extension on a generic protocol cannot _resolve_ the generic, as your original code was doing; the fact that that ever compiled was a bug in Swift. Only the _adopter_ of the protocol can resolve the generic. The extension can be applied conditionally depending on how the protocol is resolved, and that is what the `where` clause does.

Comment: Thank you so much matt! It seems my extension also needs to keep `typealias CompletionHandler = (Data?, URLResponse?, Error?) -> Void`, otherwise, a lot of my other code would complain it's not conforming to the NetworkClientType protocol.